# When will the .NET garbage collector release this object?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

```
Employee obj = new Employee();

obj.Dispose(); //statement 1;
obj = null; //statement 2
```

On which statement will the GC remove the object?

Exactly what will be happening behind the scene on statement 1 and statement2

Comment: Which language are you talking about?

Comment: @FelipeSulser in .net

Answer (score 1):

It could be any of those, or none.

If the default constructor and the `Dispose` method have no side-effects and the compiler can see that, it could skip code generation for your snippet altogether, by considering the whole thing a no-op.

Alternatively, if only the `Dispose` method is a no-op, then the GC could collect the object just after this line:

```
Employee obj = new Employee();
```

Alternatively, if the GC can prove that the object is never read again after `Dispose` ([even if it's still in scope](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100810-00/?p=13193)), it could collect the object just after this line:

```
obj.Dispose();
```

Alternatively, if the GC can't prove any of these, it could do it any time after this line:

```
obj = null;
```

Alternatively, if the GC doesn't see any pressure to recycle memory, [it might not collect the object at all](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203/) during the entire execution of the program.